# ASP Net - Page Close Event In ASP.NET?

Tags: c#

How can i get the Page Close Event In ASP.NET?? but without Java script

Comment: Why do u need this? There will be alternatives for ur need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Page Close event is a *broswer* event. You can't interact with it directly in C#.

Answer (score 6):

That is not possible as no request is sent to the server when you leave a page.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Handles Events by posting back to itself. Since this doesn't happen when a page is closed, ASP.NET **can not** handle this type of event.

Keep in mind though, that ASP.NET generates a good amount of Javascript on its pages by default, so you shouldn't be completely against handling this kind of Browser Event in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on how to do it [here](http://aspalliance.com/1294_codesnip_handle_browser_close_event_on_the_serverside) but it uses ajax and page methods. I don't think it is possible without using any javascript at all.